# Issue with number of threads on Cplex

Tags: python, cplex

I'm solving a bunch of similar problems and I want to compare them. To do so, I need everything to run on one thread. Even by setting the number of threads to 1, the model still runs on 8 threads. Has anyone ever encountered this problem? and is there a way to fix it? (I'm using Cplex with python)

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using context as explained [here](http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.model.html). An example of modeling with docplex (shown below) indicates that you can change the default setting for solver options in cplex using the following code:

```
context = Context.make_default_context()
context.cplex_parameters.threads = 1
model = Model(context=context
```

Alternatively the code can be as follow:

```
model = Model()
model.context.cplex_parameters.threads = 1
```

Or if you are using Pyomo the following solver option will be used:

```
mysolver = SolverFactory('CPLEX')
mysolver.options['threads'] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

let me change the [zoo example](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/) for your need. (Number of threads)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')

mdl.parameters.threads=1


nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()



print("threads = ",mdl.parameters.threads.get())


for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

which gives

```
threads =  1
nbBus40  =  6.0
nbBus30  =  2.0
```